# Python: Crossplatform code to download a valid .zip file

Tags: python, windows, download, zip

I have a requirement to download and unzip a file from a website. Here is the code I'm using:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

    #geoipFolder = r'/my/folder/path/ '     #Mac/Linux folder path
    geoipFolder = r'D:\my\folder\path\ '    #Windows folder path
    geoipFolder = geoipFolder[:-1]          #workaround for Windows escaping trailing quote
    geoipName   = 'GeoIPCountryWhois'
    geoipURL    = 'http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoIPCountryCSV.zip'

    import urllib2
    response = urllib2.urlopen(geoipURL)

    f = open('%s.zip' % (geoipFolder+geoipName),"w")
    f.write(repr(response.read()))
    f.close()

    import zipfile  
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(r'%s.zip' % (geoipFolder+geoipName))
    zip.extractall(r'%s' % geoipFolder)
```

This code works on Mac and Linux boxes, but not on Windows. There, the .zip file is written, but the script throws this error:

```
    zipfile.BadZipfile: File is not a zip file
```

I can't unzip the file using Windows Explorer either. It says that:

```
    The compressed (zipped) folder is empty.
```

However the file on disk is 6MB large.

Thoughts on what I'm doing wrong on Windows?

Thanks

Comment: You probably don't need to mess with `urlopen`. You could simply use `urlretrieve(URL, path_to_file)`.

Answer (score 3):

Your zipfile is corrupt on windows because you're opening the file in write/text mode (line-terminator conversion trashes binary data):

```
f = open('%s.zip' % (geoipFolder+geoipName),"w")
```

You have to open in write/binary mode like this:

```
f = open('%s.zip' % (geoipFolder+geoipName),"wb")
```

(will still work on Linux of course)

To sum it up, a more pythonic way of doing it, using a `with` block (and remove `repr`):

```
with open('{}{}.zip'.format(geoipFolder,geoipName),"wb") as f:
     f.write(response.read())
```

EDIT: no need to write a file to disk, you can use `io.BytesIO`, since the `ZipFile` object accepts a file handle as first parameter.

```
import io
import zipfile  

with open('{}{}.zip'.format(geoipFolder,geoipName),"wb") as f:
    outbuf = io.BytesIO(f.read())

zip = zipfile.ZipFile(outbuf)  # pass the fake-file handle: no disk write, no temp file
zip.extractall(r'%s' % geoipFolder)
```

Comment: You're right twice Jean-François!  I needed both the "wb" and also to remove repr() to get a valid .zip file on Windows.  Merci beaucoup!!

Comment: check my edit, you can avoid the temp .zip file. Please accept the answer you feel it solves your problem.